# Restricted vs Unrestricted energy loss?

Tags: particle-physics, energy-conservation

So I was reading the PDG review on "Passage of Particles Through Matter", https://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2018-rev-passage-particles-matter.pdf and I came across the term restricted energy loss. In fact, in some other presentations and articles, I have come across the same term but the meaning is slightly unclear to me. From what I can understand, restricted energy loss refers to the energy loss of the primary charged particle due to its ionization interactions only with the medium, excluding the energy carried away by secondary particles such as delta rays.

Is that the correct interpretation? Lastly, in regards to Table 6 of Atomic and Nuclear Properties of Materials, would the $dE/dx$ value refer to the restricted case? The table in reference is linked here: https://pdg.lbl.gov/2022/web/viewer.html?file=../reviews/rpp2022-rev-atomic-nuclear-prop.pdf.

Comment: 33.2.8  has the definitions and IMO they are not general definitions, they pertain to the calculations in the chapter and are clearly defined there.

Comment: So the table linked above shows restricted dE/dx ?